# drawpoly() with float coordinates

Tags: c++, c, graphics

How to use `<graphics.h>` function `drawpoly(int numpoints, int *polypoints)` with array of float coordinates?

(I guess that's the reason polygon degenerates rotating or zooming)

Or do I need to make a function which draw a polygon with standard `line(...)`-function?

Comment: There is no graphics library in standard C, nor C++. How about reading the documentation of whatever toolkit you use? And pick the language you use. C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean THE graphics.h from Turbo C, CPU's of that age may not even be able to do floating point operations. One have to emulate fp operations with integral one, which is very slow. So, you are hoping too much.

You could live with those little errors, or just switch to some morden graphics API's.

And I don't think line() accepts float.

Comment: Every CPU capable running a compiled C is able to do floating point arithmetics.

Comment: @Olaf I think you should know that I meant there was no hardware support for floating point on certain CPU's. For I made it clear that floating point operations were emulated on such CPU's.

Comment: You should phrase your text more carefully then. But you actually don't answer the question (it cannot be answered without more info). It is more of a comment. Btw: It is unlikely OP uses a 386 or 486SX (the last x86 without FPU), but runs TC in a DOS box on a modern PC.

Comment: @Olaf Um... But Borland wouldn't know every PC had a FPU today during 1980's. And I think I anwsered the question that: BGI doesn't support floating point, the reason of it, and OP has to accept it.

Comment: You are aware all x86 CPUs support the initial x87 FPU instruction set?The compiler does not have to be aware of modern CPUs; that's the whole reason x86 has become so popular for desktop-PCs.

Comment: @Olaf Strickly speaking not **supporting** it just recognize the prefix and send the instruction to the coprocessor or trigger an interrupt if without a FPU built-in. And it is still meaningless for a API at that time to add support for floating point, little benefit and super slow. Yes, the compiler don't have to worry about it, but it has nothing to do with the compiler. (P.S. Relying on the interrupt is still quite slower than not using x87 instructions at all.)

Comment: You confuse library functions and language features. I never wrote that specific function (or library) would take floats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136677/discussion-between-bluewanderer-and-olaf).